# Fading one div out and another one in, in it's place

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There are 3 `div`s and 3 links.

Only one `div` should be displayed at a time. When user clicks on a link for one of the other `div`s, the current one should fade out and the selected one should fade in, in place of the previous `div`.

Here is the code at the moment:

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        switches = $('#switches > li');
        slides = $('#slides > div');
        switches.each(function(idx) {
                $(this).data('slide', slides.eq(idx));
            }).click(
            function() {
                switches.removeClass('active');
                slides.removeClass('active').fadeOut('slow');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $(this).data('slide').addClass('active').fadeIn('slow');
            });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
    <style style="text/css">
        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
        li:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        #switches .active {
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        #slides div {
          display: none;
        }

        #slides div.active {
          display: block;
        }

        .outer {
            position: absolute;
        }
        .outer div {
            width: 600px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        #uno {
            background-color: red;
        }
        #dos {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        #tres {
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
```

**HTML**

```
    <ul id="switches">
        <li class="active">First slide</li>
        <li>Second slide</li>
        <li>Third slide</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="outer" id="slides">
        <div class="active" id="uno">
            First div.
        </div>
        <div id="dos">
            Second div.
        </div>
        <div id="tres">
            Third div.
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can view the page here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6920023/proofOfConcept.html

I'm attempting to use standard Jquery to do this, but clearly there is something wrong with my javascript code.

Can you spot what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: @3nigma That was all part of the fun of the question :P But if you really want to know read the second paragraph of the question and check out this link http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6920023/proofOfConcept.html, notice the discrepancy?

Comment: i was bit hasty just didn't want to delete the comment ... anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS defines a `div` that's not active as hidden. So as soon as you remove the `active` class, it will be hidden immediately.

So, remove this entry:

```
    #slides div {
      display: none;
    }
```

And add something like this on page load:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slides div:not([class="active"])').hide();
}); // will hide inactive slides initially but not always
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I've also added "position: absolute;" to '.outer div {}' to get them to align on top of each other.

Comment: That's nice to hear. @downvoter: Could you please elaborate as to what might improve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you use `slides.removeClass('active').fadeOut('slow');`. So first it will remove the **active** class, which means (according to your CSS) that it will be a regular div, thus with the property `display: none;`.

So your div is automatically hidden. It's only afterwards that you do your `fadeOut('slow')`, on a hidden div thus.

Better would be to do something like:

```
$('div.active').fadeOut(1000).delay(1000).removeClass('active');
$(this).delay(2000).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you definitely found something I hadn't noticed :)

Answer (score 0):

This works, if I understand the question correctly.

The issue is that you can't fade in an element that is hot hidden or unchcanged.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            switches = $('#switches > li');
            slides = $('#slides > div');
            switches.each(function(idx) {
                    $(this).data('slide', slides.eq(idx));
                }).click(
                function() {
                    switches.removeClass('active');
                    slides.removeClass('active').fadeOut('slow').hide();
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    $(this).data('slide').addClass('active').fadeIn('slow');
                });
        });
    </script>
```